# Documentation post ban for users that continuously post low-quality examples

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

I have noticed some users are continuously posting low quality examples to Documentation that somehow gets approved - it is another problem with reviewers approving just about anything - and then subsequently more experienced users go in and delete such low-quality content.

I think there should be post ban (or some kind of post slowdown) for such users that continuously post examples that don't satisfy even minimum quality standards. For instance - examples with just bare code without no explanation whatsoever, examples starting new topics that don't justify a separate topic and/or are already covered in another topic and similar.

Specifically, I have seen such examples posted in Android and Swift Documentation.

For instance, the same user has created several topics and all of them have now been deleted. And examples have been rejected during the review process too, but not by enough users and they ended up being approved.

[image]

---

While it could be hard to determine who contributed to a bad example when there are multiple posters involved, each topic as well as the example has an original author. If a post gets deleted before others have contributed then ownership is clear.

Comment: Maybe an example of this behavior(Without shamming a specfic user)would help your case?

Comment: What signal do we use to find said low quality examples? there's downvotes, but i haven't seen them used that well in SO Docs. Not to mention how do you connect the vote to a user when examples aren't owned by any specific user.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks. I really should pay attention to my spelling though.

Comment: @leaf It happens to us all.  I deleted the comments.

Comment: @leaf Well, it is hard to point to example without shaming the specific user... but I tried to add some...

Comment: @KevinB Examples as well as topics have original author, if that example gets deleted without anyone else contributing then you certainly have clear owner.

Comment: I've noticed similar problem in other tags.How they get approved is through drive-by approval by other low-rep users looking to gain rep by just approving everything. usually such users have no interest, experience or past SO history relating to the tag in question. E.g. user who's profile states web dev college student is approving very LQ docs in assembly or the like. Not only do they not have long enough history with SO to understand properly what it is that constitutes HQ or LQ, they haven't in clue in the tag's subject.

Comment: Define low quality. Without a definition, you're asking to ban users based on a subjective measurement.

Comment: not approving is *mean* and we have rules about being mean around here!

Comment: @Cypher - what priviledges on SO are not *subjective* in their application?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Hah. Fair point. :)

Comment: @Cypher If post gets deleted soon after being posted that should be some indicator it is low quality or at least that something else is wrong with it. If user continuously gets examples removed something is definitively not right.

Answer (score -2):

We can use the logic we used when implementing question/answer bans.

- Step 1) Go through all examples the user has ever created (including deleted ones) to check their scores and identify if they're low quality or not
- Step 2) If enough examples of the user are low quality, then display this variation of the dreaded "You're banned from asking" message:

## Sorry, we're no longer accepting examples from this account.

After implementing this, we should do one of the following:

- Make [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) concern about Documentation examples. This should be done by a moderator because both the question and its answer are locked.
- Create a new FAQ entry that basically asks "What can I do when getting 'We're no longer accepting examples from this account'?"

Comment: How do you tell they are low quality?  How do you know what part of the vote was for their content and what part is from another editor?

Comment: Well, IIRC it is hard to tell which examples meet LQ criteria without deep review by conducting further search and research. Even the quality border itself still dubious at this time, but at least an example should provide explanation like good answers have.

Answer (score -2):

To draw on comments from @Toby and others above, let's show more of the proposer's and reviewer's expertise:

**MORE ON THE AUTHOR**

Do you provide a synopsis of a user beyond their name?

All you have to currently go on In Review Documentation is on the right:

```
submitted by XYZ
9 mins ago
```

Could you put the score and badge total there next to name to help judge skill?

**DOCUMENTATION TAG SCORE**

And to go further on expertise.

Could you isolate the score (from Stack Overflow, not just Beta) in the current [tags] of a question so a reviewer can judge if this person's acceptance meets muster, especially when they provide no comments to explain their acceptance or rejection?

For example, if question is on [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) I would have:

```
*My Beta badge*
1507 0 1 2

*My Stack Overflow badge*
1507 1 12 35

*My skills in the tag* in this case PHP from tags
`php` 0 points

And show the users *next best tag(s)* (as they might have relevance).
46 `r` x 60
```

I should therefore, if the documentation to review is beyond simply grammar changes, give it a skip. And others reviewing my work on PHP would be able to take a view on my review if I did attempt it.

How does this sound?

Comment: The contributions in Documentation (or anywhere on SO) should be evaluated on their own, not by who posted them. A great user can make a bad post, and vice versa. Besides, a tag score is a poor indicator of knowledge.

Comment: Yes, but that is why we have upvotes to answers to indicate quality and usefulness. That is not part of the Documentation review as it stands (which needs expertise and effort for it to be a useful resource).  So what other suggestions do you have to guide reviewers of edits?

Comment: Reviewing should be done based on merit of the post. Fact that reviewers are letting through all kinds of things does not mean that user with low reputation cannot make perfectly good documentation example.

Comment: I agree having had made no contributions to a tag does not preclude knowledge. My idea was that it could guide a reviewer as to how diligently they should review. A low rep and no tag knowledge means check better not blindly accept. But let's see what other ideas people come up with.

Comment: Every item should be reviewed with equal diligence.

Comment: @S.L.Barth While this "We should not evaluate content based on who writes it" is real and right on main, we're speaking about documentation here. I disagree that everybody should be able to post equally there. Experts on a topic should have priority, while beginners should not be allowed to post their limited view on a topic. To a certain extent. I have no clue about c++, but if I was to post a small insight of my understanding on doc.so, it would almost certainly be a bad approach, be it approved or not.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Documentation gets voted on, and reviewed, just like Main. The problems arise from the fact that the reviewing (and probably the voting) isn't done properly. If we could rely on proper voting and reviewing, bad Documentation entries would disappear and good ones rise.